# Calling an actionlistener from another class or somehow order the multiple actionlisteners that are placed on one button?

Tags: java, button, action, actionlistener, tic-tac-toe

For my tic tac toe project, I am have an actionlistener for the buttons in my TTTBoard Class which updates the score when a player has won and an actionlistener in GUI which updates the scoreboard to show the scores.

However when I run the code, the actionlistener for GUI seems to go before the actionlistener for the TTTBoard. So what happens is that I am always one click behind.

Here is what it looks like on console
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6ysJT.png)

Here is a part of my TTTBoard Code

```
public class TTTBoard extends JPanel implements ActionListener
{
    private TTTSquare[][] square;
    private ScoreBoard gameScore;
    private Random generator = new Random();
    private int turn = 0;
    private int a = 0;
    private int p = 0;
    public TTTBoard(ScoreBoard sb)
    {
        super(new GridLayout(3,3));
        square = new TTTSquare[3][3];
        for(int r = 0; r < 3; r++)
        {
            for(int c = 0; c < 3; c++)
            {
                square[r][c] = new TTTSquare();
                add(square[r][c]);
                square[r][c].addActionListener(this);
            }
        }
        gameScore = sb;
    }
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        gameScore = new ScoreBoard();
        TTTSquare btn = (TTTSquare)e.getSource();
        btn.clicked();
        turn++;
        if(winningMove(1))
        {
            a++;
            gameScore.setPlayer(a);
        }
        else
        {
            if(turn < 5)
            {
                computersTurn();
                if(winningMove(2))
                {
                    p++;
                    gameScore.setComputer(p);
                }
            }
            else
            {

            }
        }
        System.out.println("GameScore From Loop "+gameScore.getPlayer()+" , "+gameScore.getComputer());
        System.out.println();
        gameScore.update();
    }
}
```

Here is my GUI code

```
public class GUI extends JFrame
{
    private TTTBoard board;
    private ScoreBoard score;
    private JButton btnGame;
    private JButton btnReset;
    public GUI()
    {
        super();
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        JPanel pnlSouth = new JPanel();
        score = new ScoreBoard();
        pnlSouth.add(score);

        board = new TTTBoard(score);
        add(board,BorderLayout.CENTER);

        for(int r = 0; r < 3; r++)
        {
            for(int c = 0; c < 3; c++)
            {
                board.getSquare(r,c).addActionListener
                (
                    new ActionListener()
                    {
                        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
                        {
                            System.out.println("GameScore From GUI "+board.getGameScore().getPlayer()+" , "+board.getGameScore().getComputer());
                            score.setPlayer(board.getGameScore().getPlayer());
                            score.setComputer(board.getGameScore().getComputer());
                        }
                    }   
                );
            }
        }

        }
}
```

I could only think of two ways to solve this problem and that is either by somehow ordering the two action events that occur on the button so that the action event from the TTTBoard goes before that in the GUI

Or by calling the actionlistener from TTTBoard in the GUI Class maybe like something at the bottom:

```
        for(int r = 0; r < 3; r++)
        {
            for(int c = 0; c < 3; c++)
            {
                board.getSquare(r,c).addActionListener
                (
                    new ActionListener()
                    {
                        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
                        {
                            /*
                            for(int r = 0; r < 3; r++)
                            {
                                for(int c = 0; c < 3; c++)
                                {
                                    board.getSquare(r,c).addActionListener(SOMEHOW CALL ACTIONLISTENER FROM ANOTHER CLASS);
                                }
                            }
                            */
                            System.out.println("GameScore From GUI "+board.getGameScore().getPlayer()+" , "+board.getGameScore().getComputer());
                            score.setPlayer(board.getGameScore().getPlayer());
                            score.setComputer(board.getGameScore().getComputer());
                        }
                    }   
                );
            }
        }
```

I guess my last resort is to bring the huge chunk of code from TTTBoard Class to GUI and see if it works then, but I really do not want to do that. Any help, advise, suggestions is needed and welcomed.

Thank you so much

Comment: Why do you need 10 `ActionListeners`?

Comment: Are there better ways? I just got started on GUI because I want to do something special for my final project ( A lot of stuffs I am working with is very new to me so I do not know all my options)

Comment: I'd recommend creating a *single* `ActionListener` that contains all the logic required when the user performs an action. I don't see why `TTTBoard` has any need for one. Is something supposed to happen when you click on the board outside of the squares?

Comment: :D Okay, that is where I am going to next. I was just wondering if there are any shortcuts that I can use so I do not have to mess up my code again.